# Why null field for foreign key?

Tags: python, django

Using django 1.11

I am using an API backend for a django accounts project. The following is an example of a class:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
import datetime

class Credit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payment_reference = models.IntegerField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='Paypal')
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='Ireland')
    payment_location = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='On-site')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The standard user was over-written in another app called profiles and I have included this in settings.py - 'AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profiles.User'

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

class Profile(UserManager):
    def _create_user(self, username, email, password,
                     is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given username must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=email, email=email,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class User(AbstractUser):
    objects = Profile()
```

When I try to run makemigrations however I am told that I am trying to change the nullable field 'user' to non-nullable without a default. Why would I need a default if im making reference to the active user? I want the foreign key value to **be** the active user object. And that way can filter instances of Credit to only show those with the foreign key of the logged in user.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're told that you are trying to change the nullable field 'user' to non-nullable without a default because that's exactly what you have:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

If there were any existing rows for the `Credit` model, your database would not be able to add the column because you have not specified a default and are not allowing `null`.

Once the `user` column is populated for all existing rows in the database, it is possible for you to add the not-null constraint.

The `makemigrations` script allows you to specify a one-off default when adding a column with `null=False`. This can be useful if your table does not contain any rows yet.

Comment: Absolutely right. Let me just add, because it might be unclear to the asker, that the current state of the database is and should be transparent to a migration. Meaning, if we are removing nullable attribute, there has to be some default specified so that the migration works in all the cases and on all the databases needed.